# Python - Plot two textbox and join them by a line

Tags: python, plot, tree

I have a small project in Python but I need your help... My project involves creating and displaying some sort of decision tree but I want to be completely free in the shape of everything (box, line, text inside the box).

Do you think it is possible to draw two boxes with text inside and a line connecting them? Without a module that wouldn't let me change what I want (This [link](https://zupimages.net/up/22/39/8ms9.png) shows what I would like)?

I thought about using the simple plt.text() function, but then joining the two boxes with a line, in a nice way, is still impossible for me.

Any ideas?

EDIT : I find a way thanks to a comment indicating me to use 'annotate'. The result is not perfect but it is working (I'm not a programmer so, sorry for the not-so-clean code ^^')

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# My text will be loaded as a list like the following
list_text1 = ['Cat A', 'Item 1', 'Item 2']
text1 = r'$\bf{' + str(list_text1[0]) + '}$'
for i in range(len(list_text1)-1):
    text1 = text1 + '\n' + str(list_text1[i+1])


list_text2 = ['SubCat A.1', 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'] 
text2 = r'$\bf{' + str(list_text2[0]) + '}$'
for i in range(len(list_text2)-1):
    text2 = text2 + '\n' + str(list_text2[i+1])


list_text3 = ['SubCat A.2', 'Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C']    
text3 = r'$\bf{' + str(list_text3[0]) + '}$'
for i in range(len(list_text3)-1):
    text3 = text3 + '\n' + str(list_text3[i+1])

# Location of my text-box
area1 = [0.5, 0.8]
area2 = [0.2, 0.3]
area3 = [0.8, 0.3]


# Displaying
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
an1 = ax.annotate(text1, xy=area1,
                  va="bottom", ha="center",
                  bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"))
an2 = ax.annotate(text2, xy=area1, xytext=area2, va="center", ha="left",
                  bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                  arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", relpos=(0.5,1)))
an3 = ax.annotate(text3, xy=area1, xytext=area3, va="center", ha="left",
                  bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                  arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", relpos=(0.5,1)))

plt.show()
```

Thank you !

Comment: If you would like to work in the matplotlib setting (you mentioned plt) [Annotate](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) with [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/annotate_simple_coord01.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-annotate-simple-coord01-py)s similar to yours could be a good start for you.

Comment: or you could use `tkinter`.   however, the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example